# safari 5.1.7 can't align input placeholder text center

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

here is my code:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" id="surname">
```

css

```
::i-block-chroms, input[placeholder]::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      text-align:center;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      text-align:center;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      text-align:center;
}
```

How you see I wrote in a different ways for aligning placeholder text center, also I gave text-align:center; right to input, but no success, don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe so?

```js
jQuery(function () {

    $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            if (this.originalType) {
                this.type = this.originalType;
                delete this.originalType;
            }
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
        }
    }).blur(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == '') {
            if (this.type == 'text') {
                this.originalType = this.type;
                this.type = 'text';
            }
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
        }
    }).blur();
    
});
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body{
    margin: 30px;
}
input {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 1em; 
 text-align: center;
}

::i-block-chroms, 
input[placeholder]::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      text-align:center;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      text-align:center;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
      text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Surname" placeholder="Surname" id="surname">
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitriy again, I had some issues with this code when you are giving placeholder value to input val, is there any way to center placeholder text without  giving it as input value pls?